# What is correct: "we prove statement X by / by using / with / through / ..."

Tags: prepositions

First, I'm sorry for any duplicates (although I could not find a similar question).

My question is: how do I correctly fill in the **???** in the following sentence?

> We prove Statement X **???** the following equivalences.

I'm not sure what to use: by, by using, with, through, ...
The meaning is that we use the equivalences to prove the statement.

Thank you! Dan

Comment: They all work, but "The following equivalences prove Statement X" would probably be a better sentence all the way around.

Comment: I agree with your suggestion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this context, there is no real difference between "by," "by using," and "through." Saying "with" leaves open the possibility that these were necessary but not sufficient for the proof.

However, as I said in the comment above, I think "The following equivalences prove Statement X" works better in general.

Answer (score 1):

Any of them. Why should there be only one 'correct' answer?

Comment: I thought that there might be a preferred one.